# TeamCity: how to set an absolute commit message prefix with Subversion?

Tags: svn, teamcity

I'm trying to implement [Storing Project Settings in Version Control](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/storing-project-settings-in-version-control.html) approach on a new project in TeamCity 2020.1.4 (build 78906).

As a VCS Subversion is used. Also there is a pre-commit hook which rejects all the commits when their commit message does not start from a `ISSUE-ID` or `??`.

TeamCity successfully authenticated in a Subversion VCS root but failed to make an initial commit of the settings.

By default TeamCity makes following commit message (pre-commit hook reports the inital message):

```
USERNAME: TeamCity change in '<Root project>' project: commit current project settings
```

Next in the docs [Committing Current Project Settings to VCS](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/storing-project-settings-in-version-control.html#Displaying+Changes) there is a note:

> When TeamCity commits settings into a VCS, it uses the standard commit
> message noting the TeamCity user as the committer and the project
> whose settings have changed. It is possible to add a fixed custom
> prefix to each settings' change committed by TeamCity via the
> `teamcity.versionedSettings.commitMessagePrefix` internal property, for
> example, `teamcity.versionedSettings.commitMessagePrefix=TC Change\n\n`.

Brilliant! I set up an [internal property](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-teamcity-server-startup-properties.html#TeamCity+internal+properties) like this:

```java
teamcity.versionedSettings.commitMessagePrefix=?? TeamCity settings autocommit.
```

Trying again, but the **prefix is placed after the username**:

```
USERNAME: ?? TeamCity settings autocommit. TeamCity change in '<Root project>' project: commit current project settings
```

Why? I set up a PREFIX!

Of course, [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/storing-project-settings-in-version-control.html#FAQs) there is a note

> Q. Who are the changes authored by?
>
> A. If the settings are changed via
> the user interface, in Git and Mercurial a commit in the VCS will be
> performed on behalf of the user who actually made the change via the
> UI. For Perforce as well as Azure DevOps Server (formerly TFS), the
> name of the user specified in the VCS root is used, and in **Subversion**
> **the commit message will also contain the username of the TeamCity user**
> who actually made the change via the UI.

but how to disable or rearrange the message? The pre-commit hook customization is not a good way.

I've also tried to find more Internal Properties, a complete list may be, but just found a ticket [Add centralized list of internal properties and their purpose to the wiki/documentation](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000183319-Add-centralized-list-of-internal-properties-and-their-purpose-to-the-wiki-documentation) referencing to still opened task [Create a reference page in documentation with a list of all internal properties already mentioned on other pages](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-27490).

How could I make the TeamCity's Subversion commit message started from `??`?

Answer (score 0):

I've avoided the problem using a hack with `username`: TeamCity allows to use dashes and spaces in a `username` and I created the a user with the `username` set to `ISSUE-ID bla-bla`.

But I still hope there is a way to change the prefix properly.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been much easier to change your rejection rule? However, I do not understand the special treatment for Subversion from the very beginning. What is the user name in the commit comment for? It doesn't make any sense to me... Some things are just strange at TeamCity...